# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource in Keycloak 21

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, keycloak

I'm trying to configure React app to work with Keycloak 21 and Spring Boot gateway. When I open remotely hosted React page and page a GET request I get error into browser:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://ip/realms/admin_console_realm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=admin_console_client&scope=openid&state=ze9ujRxcOaI9PhgKXozIsGd0VDCnjXSF9-u_t_8bXA0%3D&redirect_uri=http://ip/login/oauth2/code/keycloak&nonce=O9rOLQ0HH-eHZFi76hW08w2r3aCmn2Enm8df68HQvBA' (redirected from 'https://ip/api/microservice/dashboard/test') from origin 'https://xxxxxxx-xi.vercel.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Unfortunately all solutions on Google are for old version of Keycloak. Do you know into the latest version any working solution?

EDIT: I use nginx configured as a reverse proxy with this setup:

```
server {
    server_name api2.domain.org;
    index index.html index.htm;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/bmiapp.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/bmiapp-error.log error;

    location / {

        
            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*' always;
                add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers '*';

                return 204;
            }

            if ($request_method != 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*' always;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers '*';
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods '*';
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials 'true';
            }

        proxy_pass http://ip:8138;
}


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api2.domain.org/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api2.domain.org/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}


server {
    if ($host = api2.domain.org) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name api2.domain.org;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

But I get error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://api2.domain.org/api/microservice/dashboard/test' from origin 'https://main.dyyfxsm3lnw8e.amplifyapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field mode is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Is there some solution how to fix this error?

Comment: It seems your gateway/proxy adds a header 'mode' to the requests sent to Keycloak, but Keycloak only allows the headers `Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers`. They are hardcoded in org.keycloak.services.resources.Cors and not configurable.

Comment: See https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/12682, maybe it is what hits you

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, you can update your Nginx configuration to explicitly allow the `mode` header in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` directive. Modify your Nginx configuration as follows:

```
    location / {
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*' always;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers '*';

            # Add 'mode' to the list of allowed headers
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'mode';

            return 204;
        }
```

By adding `add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'mode';`, you explicitly allow the `mode` header in the CORS policy. Restart Nginx after making these changes for the configuration to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

add your IP address or domain name with port and scheme on the client configuration page under Web origins e.g. `Web Origins https://xxxxxxx-xi.vercel.app`

Comment: I tried it but it's not working. Other ideas?

Comment: Can you share the header for request and response from the web browser network tab as well as the config of the client?

Comment: I'm not sure how to paste here everything. Can you try to open the test environment: https://main.dyyfxsm3lnw8e.amplifyapp.com   Credentials are test/qwerty

Comment: The issue is not with keycloak add allowing web origins in your APIs or backend, your backend API (https://api2.hireya.org/api/microservice/dashboard/test) is blocking, add https://main.dyyfxsmlnw8e.amplifyapp.com/* to allow origins on your CORS setting, if you can show me your cors setting in your backend